# Problema al heredar clase PDO en class Conexion

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos, planteo mi problema. Cree una clase llamada Conexión en la cual tengo el método constructor que contendrá mi conexión. Se me presentan dos problemas:

1- Al crear la clase Conexion de esta manera:

```
<?php

class Conexion{
    private $con;

    public function __construct(){

        try{
            $this->con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poo_pdo','root','');

        }catch(PDOExcepcion $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }

    //Metodo para llamar la conexion y decirle que se va a ejecutar una query
    public function consultaSimple($sql){
        $this->con->prepare($sql); 
    }

    //Metodo para retornar lo que se consulte
    public function consultaRetorno($sql){
        $datos= $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $datos->execute();
        return $datos;
    }
}
?>
```

De esta forma se conecta bien sin problemas, pero al yo ejecutar métodos como por ejemplo un método que contenga una consulta según id me arroja un error, el cual me dice que el método prepare() o el execute() o cualquiera de los métodos pertenecientes a PDO me dice que el método no esta definido en la clase Conexión, he estado buscando y según lo que he visto es porque debo heredar la clase PDO en mi clase conexión, pero no se si esta es la única solución al problema, lo he intentado de la forma que menciono heredando la clase PDO y funciona sin problemas. Pero ahora se me presenta la siguiente inquietud cuando heredo la clase PDO en mi clase conexion, quedando de esta manera:

```
<?php 

class Conexion extends PDO {

   private $type = 'mysql';
   private $host = 'localhost';
   private $db = 'ojeda';
   private $user = 'root';
   private $pass = ''; 

   public function __construct() {
      //Sobreescribo el método constructor de la clase PDO.
      try{

         parent::__construct($this->type.':host='.$this-
      >host.';dbname='.$this->db, $this->user, $this->pass);

      }catch(PDOException $e){
         echo $e->getMessage();
         exit;
      }
   } 
} 
?>
```

Al tenerla de esta manera funciona tambien, pero entonces al momento de usar namespace antes de mi clase Conexion y al cargar el autoload me arroja un error el cual me dice que la clase PDO no existe, no entiendo para nada porque me dice eso. Los namespace los coloque del mismo nombre que la carpeta que contiene el archivo. Pero de verdad no se porque pasa esto. Si alguien puede aclararme la duda se lo agradezco.

Comment: en mi clase conexion yo no tengo extends PDO, ni se que función tendrá... si quieres te puedo compartir mi clase conexión en respuesta que es bien similar

Comment: Pues lo que logre entender es que extends PDO hereda la clase PDO para que puedan funcionar los metodos prepare, execute entre otros pero no creo que solo sea la forma de solucionarlo. Me parece bien Kevin su puedes compartir tu clase para guiarme.

Comment: creo que no me oriento en el tema de PHP PDO :(

Comment: Ok Kevin. Gracias igual por intentar ayudar

Comment: Si `Conexion` está bajo un namespace, PHP intentará encontrar `PDO` en el mismo namespace. Tendrías que referenciarla, en ambos casos, como `\PDO` para señalar que pertenece al namespace global. Lo mismo con `\PDOException`. Igual sería interesante ver qué error te da lo primero. Si el primer ejemplo lo usas con namespace, debiera arrojarte error en el constructor.

Comment: Saludos amenadiel, en efecto he usado \PDO y me ha dejado de dar el error. He leido que cuando se usan namespace es necesario colocar eso antes de la clase global de PHP para que no de problemas. Muchas gracias por tu comentario igualmente. Y si el error lo daba en el constructor.